# Reinstall php on on debian 9 after brokeup

Tags: php, ubuntu, debian, installation

I installed php7.3 on my debian stretch system and it was working find. After I tried to install php7.3-gd, my php no longer works. when I run php i get `/usr/bin/php file not found`. When I try to reinstall php I get this error
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
php7.3 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.3 but it is not going to be installed or
                  php7.3-fpm but it is not going to be installed or
                  php7.3-cgi but it is not going to be installed

php7.3-cli : Depends: php7.3-opcache but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.24-11+deb9u4 is to be installed
php7.3-curl : Depends: libcurl4 (>= 7.44.0) but it is not installable

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Comment: Can you format it a little better?

Comment: I got same problem, the latest stable is libc6 2.28
https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=libc6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1- sudo apt-get update –fix-missing
2- sudo dpkg –configure -a
3- sudo apt-get install -f
```

one of those command should fix your broken install

Answer (score 2):

try this command:

```
apt-get install --fix-missing
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude

sudo aptitude install php7.3
```